# Post json data onclick button Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I want to post json data when button click from typescript file

This is typescript file

```
{
            type: 'button',
            id: 'save',
            className: 'btn btn-primary save-template',
            events: {
                click: evt => {
                    _this.save();
                  (<any>config).opts.onSave(evt, _this.data.formData);

                  this.formData = new FormData();
                  this.formData.append("Form", JSON.stringify(_this.data.formData));
                  this.dataService.addItem(this.formData).subscribe(
                    data => {

                    });
                }
            }
        }].concat(options.actionButtons);
```

Here is my service

```
 addItem(data: FormData) {
    const postForm = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.API_URL}/FormTemplates/PostFormTemplate`, data, {
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.httpClient.request(postForm);
  }
```

Error i have face is cannot read property 'addItem' of undefined

Edit

```
save(stage = null) {
        let _this = this;
        let data = this.data;
        if (!stage) {
            stage = this.d.stage;
        }
        let doSave = {
            xml: () => _this.xmlSave(stage),
            json: () =>
                (<any>window).JSON.stringify(_this.prepData(stage), null, '\t')
        };

        // save action for current `dataType`
        data.formData = doSave[(<any>config).opts.dataType](stage);

        // trigger formSaved event
      document.dispatchEvent(events.formSaved);
      return data.formData;
    }
```

Comment: I think in the context you're using the `this` keyword there's no `dataService`. Consider saving `this` before using it (e.g., `const that = this;`)

Comment: Are you injecting `dataService` in your component. Please post a more complete code example

Comment: @ashish.gd Yes i have injected service to comonent

Comment: It would help if you can share a more complete code example.

Comment: @ashish.gd _this.data.formData here i got json form data but when it try to call service i got error which i have mention

Comment: You are getting an error because `this.dataService` is being evaluated to `undefined` and thus not able to read any property called `addItem` on it. Looking only at the code you have shared it is not possible to infer how the `dataService` property is initialised/injected in your typescript file.

Comment: @ashish.gd So what should i mention other .ts file and service i already mention

Comment: Your "this" is not the expected context. I can see this._save() method. Where is _save() method defined. Is it same namespace as of your service

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary i have mention save() function

Comment: @RonakDumaniya My point is where is _save method defined, to better understand your this at the time of calling this.dataService. It should be something like this, class abc{ constructor(private dataService: DataService){...}  _save(){...}  and other methods  }